# Beginner Dart - VSCode creating file with project's name

Tags: visual-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, I create Dart New Project with Console Application as a template and I'm naming it "testing". In all the tutorials I've seen, `main.dart` is created in the bin folder, but mine is being created with the name I gave to the project (`testing.dart`).

Why is this happening If I'm following exactly what is says everywhere?

Comment: It does not matter what the dart files is called. If it is something that really bothers you, you should be able to just rename it.

Answer (score 0):

This was an intended change in Stagehand - the package used for generating project templates:

https://github.com/dart-lang/stagehand/pull/659

It was done to match the Pub layout described here:

https://dart.dev/tools/pub/package-layout

If you'd prefer to use `bin/main.dart`, it's fine to rename the file.